# How to fetch specific fileds in json request by url

Tags: json, react-native

I am having api call in my app, what I want is fetching the first 10 items from the json response but directly in the url not after resolving the promise.
The json file is big (400 KB).

Part of the response json is :

```
{
    "title": "Homepage",
    "id": 0,
    "version": "2.0",
    "packages": [
        {
            "nid": "818974",
            "title": "Bürgermeister aus Luxemburg und Deutschland beklagen „untragbare Zustände“ ",
            "body": "<strong class=\"teaser text-left\"><p></p>\n<p>Die Grenzkontrollen werden noch bis Mitte Mai verlängert. Mit dieser Ankündigung verärgerte der deutsche 
---
---
,
        {
            "nid": "819028",
            "title": "Platz für sanfte Mobilität, aber nicht für die „Keeseminnen“",
            "body": "<strong class=\"teaser text-left\"><p></p>\n<p>Einige Tage nach Beginn der von ArcelorMittal durchgeführten Demolierungs- und Sanierungsarbeiten auf dem 
---
---
```

The function that gets articles:

```
export async function getArticles(){

    try {
        let articles = await fetch(`url`);
        let result = await articles.json();
        return result;

    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

```
componentDidMount() {
        getArticles().then(data => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                data: data
            })
        }, error => {
            Alert.alert("Error", "Something happend, please try again")
        })
    }
```

I tried ?per_page or ?page equal to 10 after homepage, but it never works.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an API that backend developers wrote it and it is based on **REST API**, so when you call it as `GET` or `POST` and anything else you just fetch the `JSON` that the backend developers designed it.

**However**, there is a new technology that name is GraphQL. you can call API and then you just fetch the JSON what you want. Also, it must be implemented in backend but it is possible.

**Furthermore**, you can see in the documentation of the **API** if it is paginated. Then check how many results each page returns. So, if the first page returns only ten results you can add a `page_id` to the request parameters or whatever arg the documentation provides, to retrieve only the amount of results you want

Please let me know if it helped you with your issue.